# Creating VSPackage targeting .net 3.5 and 4

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a vspackage that works fine in vs2012, but when I change the target to 4 or 3.5 to target older version, I get compile error :

Error 17  The type or namespace name 'PackageRegistrationAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and there is no reference to be added for microsoft.visualstudio.shell.10.0 and 9
Is it possible to create a vspackage in vs2012 for older versions ?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using some parts of the code which are not available to .NET frameworks older than the one you started project on (I suppose 4.5), you can't convert the project without previously remove that part.

Comment: Simply speaking, if you reference to some `dll` in your project, this `dll` should have an appropriate version with the target version. I think you should try searching for the correct version and reference it instead of the new version.

Comment: @fire-dragon : Thanks for your comment, I don't want to convert the project to older versions, I just want to create a vspackage to be usable by different visual studios, I want to create 3 different vspackages targeting 3.5, 4, 4.5 with required changes in source code.

Comment: @king : thanks, the problem is it, I can't find :microsoft.visualstudio.shell.10.0 and 9 in VS2012 and I don't know is it a problem of my system or the VS2012 has not it, and what is the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than add a reference to the Visual Studio SDK assemblies directly, you can add the appropriate VSSDK.* NuGet packages to your project. For example, the Shell assembly you are looking for to target .NET 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008) is [VSSDK.Shell.9](http://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.Shell.9/).

Note that Visual Studio 2010 includes .NET 4, so it is *highly* unlikely that you will need to build against .NET 3.5. Visual Studio 2008 and earlier did not support VSIX files to package extensions, so you're really going to have your work cut out if you want to develop an extension supporting those older environments.